# Using Entity Framework Core, how to handle different databases in development and production whith database-first approach

Tags: database, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I develop an application with a database-first approach. My stack is Jetbrains Rider, ASP.NET Core Blazor Server, Entity Framework Core, Azure SQL. I use Rider to deploy the app as an Azure web app.

The app is not in production yet. Right now, I have a single database. When something in the database changes (this is only partly under my control), I scaffold a new model to a directory "Models".

Now I want to add a dedicated development database. I think I can handle the different connection strings via `appsettings.json` but I don't know how to handle possible differences in model files.

What are best practises for this situation? I'm both interested in continuing to use my exact setup as well as in tipps for how to improve it. The database-first approach (with external schema changes) is kind of an important requirement but if a sensible process can't be established like this, I might be able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you can use the Database project template on Visual Studio, which will compare the scripts with the current state of the database. If needed, it will execute changes to make sure the database is up to date.

You can do the opposite too, and make sure the project database contains all the latest changes from the database.

You can find more information in here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-sql-server-database-project-with-visual-studio/